# Is there a word for "Prompted Knowledge"?

Tags: word-usage

I came across a tweet that said something along the lines of:

> Why did it have to be Iron Man, why could it not have been Fe-Male?

Had you asked me what is the symbol of Iron, I could not tell you.
Had you asked me what element the symbol Fe represents, I could not tell you.
But I know enough to relate Fe as the symbol for Iron when I see both presented together.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: It's *understanding **in context*** - which you could refer to as ***context-based interpretation*** or similar.

Comment: Can you give any reason why you'd think that there would be a word for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any single or formal word, but an idiom for the phenomenon is "[putting two and two together](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20two%20and%20two%20together)."

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it could be called **fragmented knowledge**; this phrase means that you know a good amount of information about some subject, but have little contextual connection between it.  The symbol presented together with the joke's context could be collectively called **associative cues**, hence I would also suggest **associative knowledge**. However, **associative knowledge** sounds as unnatural and artificial as the tears my mother cried while arguing with my father about money for the 10.000th time since the beginning of their toxic marriage.